How to make sure partitions are smaller than maxSize?
Suppose I convert a large CSV file (800K lines) to a DataFrame using SparkSession like this:
val lines = csv.stripMargin.split('\n')
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(lines)
val df = rdd.toDF

This toDF invocation fails:
Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 180094:0 was 169353207 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.rpc.message.maxSize (134217728 bytes). Consider increasing spark.rpc.message.maxSize or using broadcast variables for large values.
I understand what it means and don't want to increase spark.rpc.message.maxSize. So I'm going to calculate the number of partitions to divide lines so that each partition will be smaller than spark.rpc.message.maxSize.
val maxSize = ... // "spark.rpc.message.maxSize" in bytes

// Since lines may have different sizes and we don't want to check all lines
// we use maxSize * 0.8 heuristics instead of maxSize to be safe
val numPartitions = math.ceil(csv.getBytes().length / maxSize * 0.8).toInt

val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(lines, numPartitions)
val df = rdd.toDF

Does it make sense ? Is there a better way to make sure partitions are always smaller than spark.rpc.message.maxSize ?

IMO using Spark csv datasource would make much more sense df=spark.read.csv(...)

You can try to use the built-in Spark function to read CSV which should partition the input for you automatically
val df = spark.read.csv(path)

Using parallelize will load the passed list in a single partition by default unless you pass the number of partitions! For a general rule you can choose the number of partitions as:
val maxSize = ... // "spark.rpc.message.maxSize" in bytes
val numberOfCores = ... // "spark.cores.max" or "SparkContext.defaultParallelism"
val fileSize = csv.getBytes().length
val partitionSize = math.min(maxSize,  fileSize / numberOfCores).toInt
val numPartitions = math.ceil(fileSize / partitionSize).toInt

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(lines, numPartitions).toDF


Thanks ! What if I have a Spark cluster with a few workers ? I guess I should use the number of workers instead of "spark.cores.max"

There is a difference between workers and executors, workers are the demons running on machines which can run multiple executors, each executor runs on multiple cores which is the smallest unit to process a partition, so the number of tasks/partitions to process in parallel is depending on the number of cores you give to the job

Would not it be better to use SparkContext.defaultParallelism instead of "spark.cores.max" ?

I think it should work as well
